# Unable to start nfs-secure-server?

Tags: centos, nfs, kerberos

I want to make kerberized nfs server on my machine, I follow these steps:

```
/etc/krb5.keytab
systemctl enable nfs-sever; systemctl start nfs-server
systemctl enable nfs-secure-server; systemctl start nfs-secure-server
```

All the steps are fine except the  nfs-secure-server, I got this message when I tried

```
systemctl status nfs-secure-server
```

[image]

I tried to start rpc-svcgssd but I cannot.
Any help How I can start nfs-secure-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that if you use RHEL 7.0 these services will be started: nfs-secure-server and nfs-secure. 
But in RHEL 7.1 you don't need nfs-secure-server and nfs-secure anymore.

Comment: Ok ... but why the service is still present by default and that still in 7.6 8-/

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
systemctl enable nfs-secure
systemctl start nfs-secure
systemctl status nfs-secure
```

I got stuck because I was using "nfs-secure-server" and not "nfs-secure".

Comment: nfs-secure-server is related to server side & client-side is nfs-secure